# YOAST SEO plugin data into WP REST API json

Tags: wordpress

Has anyone succeeded printing Yoast SEO plugin data into WP REST API json? I was able to grab the primary category, but I have yet to find out how to grab SEO title and meta description.

Answer (score 4):

Found this nice plugin:
https://github.com/ChazUK/wp-api-yoast-seo

For updating the values you can try adding a callback to
"update_callback" in the "register_rest_field" function as in the doc example:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/

Comment: Has anyone found out how to update YOAST SEO values via this API? I am able to GET the values, but I'm trying to figure out how to PUT or POST values and programmatically set the SEO title/description via REST. Example JSON payload would be appreciated.